deep link parameters in flutter return one parameter only
I try to use deep link in flutter with go_router package, But when I try to test it
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.com/play?id=1&name=john&email=email@example.com"

I get one parameter only
and This is the route that recive the link
GoRoute(
          path: 'play',
          name: 'play',
          builder: (context, state) {
            print(state.uri);
            return const AudioPlayerScreen();
          },
        ),

when I try to print the url I get
https://example.com/play?id=1
Any help

Try this example
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamSubscription? _sub;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUniLinks();
  }

  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    _sub = linkStream.listen((String? link) {
      if (link != null) {
        print('link: $link');
      }
    }, onError: (err) {

    });
  }
}


I don't use uni_links  package, I use only go_router

Can you try this     final queryParams = state.queryParams;

gives me only {'id':1}

I found a solution I must pass parameters like this https://example.com/play/1/john/email@example.com and receive it
GoRoute(
path: 'play/:id/:name/:email',
name: 'play',
builder: (context, state) {
String? id= state.pathParameters['id'];
String? name= state.pathParameters['name'];
String? email= state.pathParameters['email'];
})
